# Удаление перекрытия между соседними многоугольниками

Tags: css3, svg

Посмотрите следующий небольшой SVG, показывающий два смежных треугольника:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" version="1.1">
   <polygon points="10,0  60,0  35,50" style="fill:#cc4444;"/>
   <polygon points="35,50 85,50 60,0" style="fill:#cc3333;"/>
</svg>
```

В моем браузере это выглядит следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обратите внимание на белую линию между полигонами.

Хотя я понимаю, что используемое смешение является причиной, но этот эффект очень раздражает, особенно, когда вы пытаетесь отобразить, например, математическую поверхность, как показано [здесь.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/381)

Какое есть правильное решение в SVG, чтобы закрыть эти белые пробелы?
Один из способов - добавить полигонам небольшой штрих по краям  одного цвета, но это для меня похоже на hack , а в графике с большим количеством полигонов такое решение  значительно увеличивает размер файла.

[Источник вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47451435/7394871)

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47451435/7394871

Answer (score 2):

Добавление `shape-rendering ="crispEdges"` в тег `<svg>` должно устранить проблему, но повсюду даст  неровные края.

Если это не устроит вас, то вы можете попробовать передать элементы изображения через фильтр, который просто растрирует изображение.

Однако это не полностью устраняет проблему и может немного понизить производительность, особенно если это  анимация изображения.

Другие варианты - добавить штрих к  полигонам, как вы предложили, или просто сделать многоугольники немного болье, чтобы они перекрывались.

```html
 <!-- Стандартный SVG -->
<svg width="180" height="180" viewBox="0 0 180 180">
<g transform="translate(90,90)">
<path d="M0 0 0.00 -90.00 70.36 -56.11Z" fill="#323232" />
<path d="M0 0 70.36 -56.11 87.74 20.03Z" fill="#4b4b4b" />
<path d="M0 0 87.74 20.03 39.05 81.09Z" fill="#646464" />
<path d="M0 0 39.05 81.09 -39.05 81.09Z" fill="#7d7d7d" />
<path d="M0 0 -39.05 81.09 -87.74 20.03Z" fill="#969696" />
<path d="M0 0 -87.74 20.03 -70.36 -56.11Z" fill="#afafaf" />
<path d="M0 0 -70.36 -56.11 0.00 -90.00Z" fill="#c8c8c8" />
</g>
</svg>

<!-- Crisp edges -->
<svg width="180" height="180" viewBox="0 0 180 180" shape-rendering="crispEdges">
<g transform="translate(90,90)">
<path d="M0 0 0.00 -90.00 70.36 -56.11Z" fill="#323232" />
<path d="M0 0 70.36 -56.11 87.74 20.03Z" fill="#4b4b4b" />
<path d="M0 0 87.74 20.03 39.05 81.09Z" fill="#646464" />
<path d="M0 0 39.05 81.09 -39.05 81.09Z" fill="#7d7d7d" />
<path d="M0 0 -39.05 81.09 -87.74 20.03Z" fill="#969696" />
<path d="M0 0 -87.74 20.03 -70.36 -56.11Z" fill="#afafaf" />
<path d="M0 0 -70.36 -56.11 0.00 -90.00Z" fill="#c8c8c8" />
</g>
</svg>

<!-- Null filter -->
<svg width="180" height="180" viewBox="0 0 180 180">
<defs>
<filter id="null">
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic"/>
</filter>
</defs>
<g transform="translate(90,90)" filter="url(#null)">
<path d="M0 0 0.00 -90.00 70.36 -56.11Z" fill="#323232" />
<path d="M0 0 70.36 -56.11 87.74 20.03Z" fill="#4b4b4b" />
<path d="M0 0 87.74 20.03 39.05 81.09Z" fill="#646464" />
<path d="M0 0 39.05 81.09 -39.05 81.09Z" fill="#7d7d7d" />
<path d="M0 0 -39.05 81.09 -87.74 20.03Z" fill="#969696" />
<path d="M0 0 -87.74 20.03 -70.36 -56.11Z" fill="#afafaf" />
<path d="M0 0 -70.36 -56.11 0.00 -90.00Z" fill="#c8c8c8" />
</g>
</svg>
```

[Источник: Prevent transparent gaps between adjacent polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47453328/7394871) @squeamish ossifrage